# RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-19'

Tags: python, asynchronous

I don't understand why in this section of code, I get these error:

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-18'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-19' ...
```

I am clearly setting the event loop?

```
async def get_data(symbolStr):
    print("Getting AR for", symbolStr)
    await amp.get_data_job(symbolStr)


for strg in strings:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        th = threading.Thread(target = asyncio.run, args=(get_data(strg),))
        th.start()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You should be using threads or asyncio, not both. Rarely would you need both (there are some exceptions).